# IK succeed for constraint-aware but fail for non-aware

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm following this tutorial http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%204 to do the inverse kinematics for my robot arm. but for the same goal position, the constraint_aware_ik succeed to find a solution while the non constraint aware ik cannot. after dig into the source code, i find that the constraint_aware_ik ultimately call the function searchPositionIK() and the non-aware ik call the getPositionIK(). my kinematics solver is the KDLArmKinematicsPlugin. is there anybody encountering the same problem as me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43309/ik-succeed-for-constraint-aware-but-fail-for-non-aware/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably what's happening is that the IK solver is unable to evolve from the seed state you provide to the desired goal. The **searchPositionIK()** method performs retries (up to 3 by default) from randomly sampled seed states if the provided one fails, while **getPositionIK()** does not.

If you want to keep using **getPositionIK()**, choose a more appropriate IK seed state.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-09-07**:
thanks for the answer. i  will try other seed states